# The show 5 results is appended to the first 5 results displayed in Jquery

Tags: jquery, select

There are 2 `javascript` functions
 1) which shows 5 results
2) which shows 10 results.
Show 5 is selected by default using the select element.

```
<select id="select" name="select" onchange="showResults(this.value);">
    <option selected="selected" value="5">Show 5</option>
    <option value="10">Show 10</option>   
</select>
```

Which executes the 1st function. However, when the user selects "show 10" option the 2nd function is executed which displays 10 results. However, the 10 results are appended to the previous 5. The `showResults` function as below:-

```
function showResults(value)
{
if (value==10)
  {
  getDiscussions10();
  }
else
    {
    getDiscussions();
    }
}
```

Am not sure where am going wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where's the code of `getDiscussions{10}()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Using my psychic powers, I am going to say that you are not emptying the container prior to adding additional items.

Use `.empty()`.

If this is not the case, please post your code.  Psychic powers are not the best debugging technique.